# HTML <img> tag is not working properly in localhost?

Tags: php, html, image, localhost

I am working on a website and I am using `xammp` as localhost server. The folder I am using is `website` which contain two sub folders `content` and `main`. I have a image `logo.png` on my `content` folder. I want to create a php document in `main` folder to view the image. For this I have used

```
<body>
  <img src="<?php echo dirname(__FILE__,2);?>/content/logo.png" >
</body>
```

But this code doesnot work and show a small black box with a cross arrow sign on Microsoft edge. Can anyone tell what's the mistake here?

Comment: Why use php in there?

Comment: Is there a reason you using php for this? what do u see on source code?

Comment: You can use the code below to make it work. If you want to know the mistake however, you will have to give us the value of `__FILE__`

Comment: @MartinDimitrov @Mark_Ed @Masivuye  Ok. The php is used because I want the image to be located dynamically and the src becomes `E:xampp/htdocs/website/content/logo.png` which is the required path for image file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to fix this problem is to have a `settings.php` or `config.php` or how ever you want to name it file located in the project root directory which in your case would be the `website` directory.

The file created in the root directory can look something like this

```php
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);

define('SITE_DOMAIN', 'http://localhost/website');

define('SITE_DIR', '/website');

define('CONTENT_DIR', SITE_DIR . '/content');

//more settings/configs......
```

> The above file example should only contain definitions of the project (paths, domains, emails, etc..) and should be included at the start of every other php file you create.

And then you create your php file in the `main` directory. Lets assume you are going to call it `image.php` and it should look something like this

```php
<?php
require '../config.php';

//...some php code here....
?>

<!-- ...some html code here... -->

<img src="<?= SITE_DOMAIN ?>/content/logo.png">

<!-- ..more html code here... -->
```

The above is only an example, you structure your file however you like.

Here are some examples of how you can do this using the above example.

**Example use 1**

```php
<img src="<?= SITE_DOMAIN ?>/content/logo.png">
```

Src output: `http://localhost/website/content/logo.png`

**Example use 2** (probably the best option)

```php
<img src="<?= SITE_DIR ?>/content/logo.png">
```

Src output: `/website/content/logo.png`

**Example use 3**

```php
<img src="<?= CONTENT_DIR ?>/logo.png">
```

Src output: `/website/content/logo.png`

> Avoid using `..` to access content files in HTML its not good practice and please do not use `dirname(__FILE__,2)` that's really bad. I say that you should not use it because can you imagine having 20 images for example on that page, that means you are going to call `dirname` 20 times and `__FILE__` 20 times to always get the same results.

The above example is also good if at some point this project becomes really big and you start moving and renaming php files you can rest assured that your images are always going to work.

---

If this is only a small project and you don't need any of what I have suggested above, you could try something like this in the php file you created in the `main` directory.

```php
<?php
define('CONTENT_DIR', '/website/content');
?>

<img src="<?= CONTENT_DIR ?>/logo.php">
```

> **Note:** I use `<?= ?>` instead of `echo`, both do exact same thing. Feel free to change it to `<?php echo '' ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You probaly doesn't PHP to locate logo.png, just use ../ to change current directory.